# I want change the volume of ringertonevolume

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

i used this code to adjust volume but it didn't work

```
int volume=23;
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,volume, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND|AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);}
```

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a very helpful description. Was there an error message? Edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should not just set the volume to 23 instead you should first make a call to  getStreamMaxVolume(StreamType) to get the max volume possible for the StreamType which in this case is the ringer's volume.

for example, to set the ringer's volume to max you do this!

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

UPDATES

```
    int streamMaxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(streamMaxVolume), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //I got 7
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, streamMaxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

ok. now that i am at home i can try out codes. here as you can see, streamMaxVolume gives me a integer of 7. if you try to set it to 23 its way too much. so the possible values you can use in setStreamVolume in my case is

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
Lowest <-----> Highest

```
//set to lowest ->
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

//set to loudest ->
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: then how can i adjust volume via programaticaly

Comment: did this line of code work for you? if it works ill give another example

Comment: @Rejinderi how can i set 30% , 60% , 100% volume but it should work in all devices ? everytime max volume is different

Comment: @ErumHannan You can do this by using simple mathematics. lets say a device max volume is 7, 30% of 7 would be 2.1 ~ 2, another device is 12 then 30% of 12 would be 3.6 ~ 4.