# How to disable increasing volume ring in Marshmallow programmatically?

Tags: android, volume, telephonymanager

I just want to disable escalating/rising/increasing volume of ringtone on incoming call. I know that there's application to do this like [Disable Increasing Ring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shumoapp.disableincreasingring&hl=en) but I'm android developer, I cant see their mobile ads just to stop my phone's increasing volume ;)

I've tried this way...

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            manager.listen(new MyPhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {            
            AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (state == 1 && manager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Incoming call from : " + incomingNumber);
                manager.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                    manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
                    FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES | FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put **0** volume, Phone state listener is working. But I think setStreamVolume() not working against increasing volume when I use **7** or `manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)` as volume.

Reference :

- [I want change the volume of ringertonevolume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964255/i-want-change-the-volume-of-ringertonevolume)
- [How to increase the ringer & notification volume programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432758/how-to-increase-the-ringer-notification-volume-programmatically-in-android)